# How to import another script file in Jshell

Tags: java, import, java-9, jshell

I'm looking to use jshell to replace bash for command line processing.

I've created a simple class fs in the file fs.jsh (yes poor naming) that has a number of utility functions like:

```
// file fs.jsh
class fs
{
    static void println(String line)
    {
         System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

I know want to include fs.jsh from another file:
e.g.

```
// helloworld.jsh
import fs.jsh

fs.println("Hello World");
```

The above code gives the error:

```
package fs does not exist
|  import fs.jsh;
```

I've also tried:

```
import fs;
```

Which gives:

```
Error:
|  '.' expected
|  import fs;
```

So how do I import one script file from another.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that you can make sure is to create an instance of the class before you access its method :

```
new fs().println("Hello World");
```

Another, do make sure the sequence in which the scripts are executed is fixed if one relies on the code of the other.

> Scripts are run in the order in which they’re entered on the command
>   line. Command-line scripts are run after startup scripts. To run a
>   script after JShell is started, use the `/open` command.

Additionally, an `import` without a package doesn't make much sense and you cannot have `package`s in Jshell snippets.

The way you can do it is somewhat like:

1. Have one script file `some.jsh`

[image]

2. Another script file `sometwo.jsh` which calls it

[image]

3. Eventually, open the script `sometwo.jsh`

[image]

Comment: I had no idea you can do that

Comment: @Eugene Its just the sequence of snippets, nothing else. There is no import as such or any kind of pointers to remember what class was owned by which script.

Comment: Interesting. So I can essentially use a series of /open statements as pseudo imports.

The new isn't required as all my method are intentionally static.

I'm playing with the idea of weaning our network engineers off using bash for system admin tasks.

I'm using static methods to keep the syntax simple.
Most network admins aren't too smart :)

Comment: @BrettSutton Indeed. Just make sure the sequence of the code would matter the most. Playing around is a good idea to discover anyway.